# Error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY When using Bulk API 2.0 to insert 850 pricebookEntries

Tags: salesforcedx, bulk-api

I am using postman to access the Bulk API 2.0 and am trying to import mass PricebookEntries into a new Pricebook. It worked seamlessly on my ScratchOrg and now it says:
`INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY`

Whole error for every object I tried to import:

```
"sf__Id","sf__Error",IsActive,UnitPrice,Product2Id,CurrencyIsoCode,Pricebook2Id
"","INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY:insufficient access rights on cross-reference id:--","true","654.62","01t0E00000A74LWQAZ","EUR","01s1x000003CNm3AAG"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem must be with permissions or also possible with the Ids.

**A first good check is:to check in the UI if you can view the Objects that failed.**

If salesforce can match the ids with Regex against the needed [format](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000324087&type=1)
and still is unable to view at the right SObject it will say it is the "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY" because it asumes you lack the permission to view the object.

So try to check the ids if the problem occures with a lot of inserts it is likely that.

Comment: Wow that really solved my problem! 
I did check the objects in the UI and those were the ones from my scratch-org!